# Express-session with MySQL storage does not save user

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I'm using express-session for handling user session in Node.js application. The problem is after rewriting it for MySQL storage it seems like after changing route all information disappears and my middleware redirects me for login page again.
My code:

```
let options = {
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    port: 3306,
    password: "",
    database: "cursova"
}
var sessionStore = new MySQLStore(options, con);

app.use(session({
    key: 'myCookie',
    secret: 'secret12345',
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        originalMaxAge: 1000 * 60 * 5,
        maxAge: 60000 * 5,
        secure: true,
        path: '/',
    }
}));
```

console results:
[image: console results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try initializing the session:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.session.init = "init";
    next();
});
```

For session, I have this:

```
const options = {
        host: config.db.host,
        port: config.db.port,
        user: config.db.user,
        password: config.db.password,
        database: config.db.database
    };

const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(options);

const expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 1 hour
app.use(session({
    store: sessionStore,
    secret: process.env.SESSIONSECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        //secure: true,
        //httpOnly: true,
        expires: expiryDate      
    }
}));
```

I am not passing the connection and do not have a key. I add in the HTTP and secure once I know it works.

Comment: init is saving through app but user info is not.

Comment: If you comment out httpOnly, does it save?

Comment: still nothing :(

Comment: Did you ever find a solution @ТаняБіланюк

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is because of "secure: true" from cookie. This means the cookie is saved only if you use HTTPS. Try setting it to false