# Why do I need to access the session object before Express-Session saves and sets a cookie?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**TLDR:**

Why do I need to access the session object

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.session.init = "init";
    next();
});
```

...in app.js after the session middleware for it to work? Not doing so means the session isn't saved, and a cookie isn't set.

****Edit:** I don't think this is an issue with cookie settings as the sessions also aren't being saved, and both cookies and sessions are fine when the above code is included

---

**Original Question:**

I'm using Express-Sessions to try and store sessions in my database (MySQL).

For some reason it stopped saving sessions and returning cookies. My Express log looked like this:

```
  express:router dispatching POST /auth/login +18s
  express:router query  : /auth/login +0ms
  express:router expressInit  : /auth/login +1ms
  express:router session  : /auth/login +0ms
  express-session no SID sent, generating session +1ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /auth/login +1ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /auth/login +0ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : /auth/login +1ms
  express:router trim prefix (/auth) from url /auth/login +0ms
  express:router router /auth : /auth/login +1ms
  express:router dispatching POST /login +0ms
```

However, if I add:

```
// *This code makes Express-Session work*
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.session.init = "init";
    next();
});
```

To my `app.js` code, as recommended [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54933931/7396516), my session then saves, and a cookie is returned

```
const options = {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE
};

const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(options);

app.use(session({
    name: process.env.SESSION_NAME,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRETS,
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'strict',
    maxAge:600000
  }
}));

// *This code makes Express-Session work*
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.session.init = "init";
    next();
});

require('./startup/headers')(app);
require('./startup/routes')(app);

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {

  const status = error.statusCode || 500;

  res.status(status).json({ message: `Error`});
});
```

and my Express log then looks like this (note the express-session lines at the end)

```
  express:router dispatching POST /auth/login +58ms
  express:router query  : /auth/login +1ms
  express:router expressInit  : /auth/login +2ms
  express:router session  : /auth/login +1ms
  express-session no SID sent, generating session +5ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /auth/login +4ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /auth/login +0ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /auth/login +3ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : /auth/login +3ms
  express:router trim prefix (/auth) from url /auth/login +1ms
  express:router router /auth : /auth/login +1ms
  express:router dispatching POST /login +0ms

  express-session saving 3FOu73E3BHGVl0Rw-KtrCOjjqcDZlxRY +31ms
  express-session set-cookie session-cookie=s%3A3FOu73E3BHGVl0Rw-KtrCOjjqcDZlxRY.ucs49AVEgJFmJ1b5CeDuICqIihbDeNa294ImU4XC2lg; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 23 Jan 2023 11:29:39 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict +9ms
  express-session split response +8ms
```

I can't see anything in the docs about this being necessary, and was hoping someone could explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that configuring

```
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false,
```

requires the session to be altered before it's created